# JMeter Maven disable log

Tags: jmeter-maven-plugin

I am facing a matter that I do not success to solve.
I am running JMeter on Jenkins using JMeter Maven Plugin.

When JMeter is started it run the non UI mode and always setup the argument -l to log infos.
That log load of lines and reach giga byte of logs. Resulting disk space to end full.

I wonder how to disable the argument -l. I found no way the control the argument JMeter is launched with.

Through the pom.xml fil I can overwrite jmeter.properties but found no tag to set up the argument for launching.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Basic Configuration](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Basic-Configuration) page of the plugin documentation:

> The following properties files will be used if they are found in ${project.base.directory}/src/test/jmeter:
>
> jmeter.properties
>
> saveservice.properties
>
> upgrade.properties
>
> system.properties
>
> user.properties
>
> global.properties

So you can totally suppress JMeter output like:

1. Add *user.properties* file to **${project.base.directory}/src/test/jmeter** folder (the same location where your script lives)
2. Add the following lines to the *user.properties* file

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
   jmeter.ave.saveservice.assertion_results=none
   jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.label=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.time=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false
   ```

Just in case you will need some metrics (i.e. if you decide to perform results analysis) you can enable individual lines.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them.

Comment: Thank you very much for that clear help. Veru much appreciated.

Comment: It still does produce a .jtl file logging load of lines.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the project wiki:

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Log-Levels

I would guess you probably want this:

```
<project>
[...]
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overrideRootLogLevel>error</overrideRootLogLevel>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
[...]
```

Comment: I tried it too but it still produce the log with the .July file.

Comment: So you are trying to not create the log file at all, rather than reduce the amount of data that is put in it?